# Fatal error: Class 'Carbon_Fields\Widget' not found

Tags: php, wordpress, carbon-fields

I'm using https://carbonfields.net/ to create custom options for wordpress theme

I tried to copy this code into functions.php:

```
use Carbon_Fields\Widget;
use Carbon_Fields\Container;





class Banner_Widget extends Widget {
    function __construct() {
        $this->setup( 'banner', __( 'Banner', 'crb' ), __( 'Displays a custom banner.' ), array(
            Field::make( 'attachment', 'image', __( 'Image' ) )
                ->set_required( true ),
            Field::make( 'text', 'link', __( 'Link' ) )
                ->set_required( true ),
        ));
    }

    function front_end( $args, $instance ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $instance[ 'link' ] ) . '">';

        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $instance[ 'image' ], 'medium' );

        echo '</a>';
    }
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_custom_widgets' );
function my_register_custom_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Banner_Widget' );
}
```

and I ended up with this:

[image]

I don't understand this error since `use Carbon_Fields\Widget;` is already found.

I was using Xampp with PHP 7+

Comment: How is your auto-loader configured? `use` does not import files or class definitions, just symbols. You either need an auto-loader or `require_once 'path/to/Carbon_Fields/Widget.php'` (or whatever the actual path is)

Comment: Have you read the [Quickstart](https://carbonfields.net/docs/carbon-fields-quickstart/?crb_version=2-2-0) documentation? There's an example of how to include the composer autoloader

Comment: @Phil I've read this documentation and I used composer, I did Field and Container look at this screenshot https://i.imgur.com/D1G14oo.png, then I want to try with "Widget" now it gave me the errors.